# Creating a time-driven trigger using REST API

Tags: google-api, google-apps-script, google-api-java-client

I was thinking to write some Java code for installing a time driven trigger (to run a google apps script periodically) for an user. But could not find REST API for manipulating triggers. Wanted to know whether it is possible yet. Thank you.

Sanjay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no REST API to manipulate triggers. However, you can write a doPost function in your script, publish it as a web app and do a POST from your Java code. 
Of course, inside your doPost() function you have to set up a trigger using the ScriptApp API.

Comment: Am unable to figure out how to do a POST to the webapp "on behalf of a google user." Is there some REST API to post to a webapp, passing a google credential? Clues could help. Thanks.

Comment: @Srik - It seems to be impossible to use the ScriptApp API from within an Apps Script WebApp as of now - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702628/creating-time-based-trigger-from-webapp